# Updating chart data, but not all bars redrawing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm working on a bar chart that updates its data based on the mouseover of another element. When the chart updates, if there are less bars in the new chart, the chart permanently has fewer bars and changing the data back does not add them back in. I've added a gif to show this - when it gets down to 3 bars, they never come back.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
var scatter_versus_dataset; // the main set
var scatter_versus_dataset_filtered;

// set versus y scale
scatter_versus_y = d3.scaleBand().range([0, SCATTER_VERSUS_HEIGHT])
// set versus x scale
scatter_versus_x_fatal = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, SCATTER_VERSUS_WIDTH / 3]);
scatter_versus_x_nonfatal = d3.scaleLinear().range([-1 * SCATTER_VERSUS_WIDTH / 3, 0 ])
// set the versus colors                   
scatter_versus_z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(STACK_COLOURS);

...

function updateScatterVersus(code){

// filter the set
scatter_versus_dataset_filtered = scatter_versus_dataset.filter(function (d) { return (d.majorOccCodeGroup == code) })

scatter_versus_y.domain(scatter_versus_dataset_filtered.map(function (d) { return d.occupation; })).padding(BAR_PADDING);
scatter_versus_x_fatal.domain([0, d3.max(scatter_versus_dataset_filtered, function (d) { return d.f_total_rate; })]).nice();
scatter_versus_x_nonfatal.domain([d3.min(scatter_versus_dataset_filtered, function (d) { return +-1 * d.nf_total_rate; }), 0]).nice();

var bars = d3.selectAll("#scatter_versus_fatal_rect")
    .data(scatter_versus_dataset_filtered)
bars.exit()
    .remove()
bars.transition()
    .duration(600)
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return scatter_versus_y(d.occupation);
    })
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return scatter_versus_x_fatal(0) + SCATTER_VERSUS_GAP_HALF;
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return scatter_versus_x_fatal(d.f_total_rate);
    })
    .attr("height", scatter_versus_y.bandwidth())

bars.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr('id', 'scatter_versus_fatal_rect')
    .classed("bar", true)
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return scatter_versus_y(d.occupation);
    })
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return scatter_versus_x_fatal(0) + SCATTER_VERSUS_GAP_HALF;
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return scatter_versus_x_fatal(d.f_total_rate);
    })
    .attr("height", scatter_versus_y.bandwidth())

}
```

The process for redrawing the other side of the chart is exactly the same. The problem is still there if i only draw one of the sides.

The data is just from a csv, and I don't think it's the problem - the filtered set has the right number of entries and it's fine in other charts. It's probably something to do with the removal and redrawing but I can't find many examples of this. Or perhaps a key? I can upload some data if needed but it's a pretty big CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` in HTML is unique, only 1 tag should have it.

Select the `div` for the bars, then selectAll tags with class is `bar` and bind data.

Remove the `id` you add to the rects.

```
var bars = d3.select("#scatter_versus_fatal_rect")
    .selectAll(".bar")
    .data(scatter_versus_dataset_filtered);

bars.enter()
    .append("rect")
    // .attr('id', 'scatter_versus_fatal_rect')
    .classed("bar", true)
    ......
```